# Google oauth Google_ServiceResource class

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

Using the `google-api-php-client`, when I use `/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php`.

I get the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Google_ServiceResource' not found in
>   `/var/www/Test1/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php`
>   on line 25

however, when I use the `Google_PlusService.php` file, it works 100%.

Am I missing something?

Comment: code formatting and add google oauth tag

Comment: I think you should read this because I have no idea why you would want to reference google_oauth2service.php  https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/user-example.php

Comment: @DalmTo Link doesnt work